# Run docker build inside Jenkins Docker Slave

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

Currently I've a CI pipeline with the following stages:

1. Build
2. Unit Tests
3. Static Code Analysis

This is how my Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage("Install") {
      steps {
        sh "npm install"
      }
    }
    stage("Build") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run build"
      }
    }
    stage("Format") {
        steps {
            sh "npm run format"
        }
    }
    stage("Lint") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run lint"
      }
    }
    stage("Test") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run test"
      }
    }
    stage("Code Coverage") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run test:cov"
        publishHTML(target: [
            reportDir: "./coverage/lcov-report",
            reportFiles: "index.html",
            reportName: "Jest Coverage Report"
        ])
      }
    }
    stage("End-To-End Testing") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run test:e2e"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add more stages to my pipeline:

1. Build and tag Docker Image from Dockerfile
2. Push the image to the Docker Hub
3. Some more steps which would need Docker CLI

Example:

```
pipeline {
  .
  .
  .
  stage("Docker Build") {
    steps {
      sh "docker build -t [user_name]/[image_name]:[tag] .
    }
  }
}
```

I'm quite new to this, and I have tried multiple ways to install docker and it was unsuccessful  and it is a bad practice too.

We can run `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...` but I can't use bind mounting while using docker build command.

Can someone please suggest me a way where I can use docker commands inside Jenkins SSH Agents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Install Docker CLI without the Daemon in Jenkins Docker Slave. I have used this [Docker Agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/ssh-agent) and installed Docker CLI inside it using this [method](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script)
2. Then as a docker daemon I've used my remote docker host. (Also, you can configure the local docker host as remote using these [steps](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/#Configure_a_Docker_Host_With_Remote_API_Important)). You can use docker remote host using --host flag. E.g. `docker --host x.x.x.x:2375 build -t johndoe:calculator .`
3. Syntax: `docker --host [Docker_Host]:[Port] build -t [Image_Name]:[Image_Tag] .`

My New Jenkinsfile is as follows:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage("Install") {
      steps {
        sh "npm install"
      }
    }
    stage("Build") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run build"
      }
    }
    stage("Format") {
        steps {
            sh "npm run format"
        }
    }
    stage("Lint") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run lint"
      }
    }
    stage("Test") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run test"
      }
    }
    stage("Code Coverage") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run test:cov"
        publishHTML(target: [
            reportDir: "./coverage/lcov-report",
            reportFiles: "index.html",
            reportName: "Jest Coverage Report"
        ])
      }
    }
    stage("End-To-End Testing") {
      steps {
        sh "npm run test:e2e"
      }
    }
    stage("Docker Build") {
      steps {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'Docker_Host', variable: 'DOCKER_HOST')]) {
          sh 'docker --host $DOCKER_HOST build -t xxx/xxx .'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: I have stored Docker host URL on Jenkins as a credential and used it using withCredentials function.*